# Compare 2 arrays with checking if keys of 1st array are close to each other in 2nd

Tags: php, arrays

So, I got two arrays. First `$main`:

```
(
    [0] => 4035
    [1] => 10065
    [2] => 10034
    [3] => 10039
    [4] => 4035     // <- this is key 0 from $inmain
    [5] => 4035     // <- this is key 2 from $inmain
    [6] => 4096     // <- this is key 1 from $inmain
)
```

And second `$inmain` that looks like this:

```
(
    [0] => 4035
    [1] => 4096
    [2] => 4035
)
```

I want to detect if all keys from `$inmain` are "close" (regardless of order) to each other in the `$main` array. E.g. you can see that they are now (but in a different order) on keys 4, 5, 6.

Comment: what does "close" mean? how close?

Comment: Keys of `$inmain` must be next to each other in `$main`, there can't be any keys splitting, just like it is right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll just convert those arrays to 'strings' like that:
`$mainstr = "1000111"` and `$inmainstr = "111"` and than use strpos()

Answer (score 1):

```
$close = false;

$perm = compute_all_permutations($inmain); // perm is a set of permutations

for($i = 0; $i < (count($main) - count($inmain)); $i++)
{
    $subperm = array();

    for($j = 0; $j < count($inmain); $j++)
    {
        $subperm[$j] = $main[$i + $j];
    }

    if($subperm is in $perm)
    {
        $close = true;
    }
}

if($close)
{
    // keys are close
}
else
{
    // keys aren't close
}
```

complexity is O(N*M!) where N is the length of $main and M is the length of $inmain

Comment: what exactly is `compute_all_permutations`

Comment: it creates a collection of vectors of the same length of the input vector. Each vector in the collection has the same values of the input one but in different order. If N is the length of the input vector, the collection contains N! vectors.

Answer (score 0):

This function might be some help to you:

```
function arrayclose($main, $inmain, $proximity=5/*adjust default here, or set on your function call*/){
 foreach($inmain as $val){
   $isclose=false;
   foreach($main as $val2){
     if(abs($val-$val2) <=$proximity)
       $isclose=true;
   }
   if(! $isclose) return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

It loops on all the items you want to check for.  Then inside that, it loops on the larger list.  Each element in the smaller array must be within `$proximity`.  If there are no hits, immediately return false.  If it gets through all the loops without returning false, that means that everything was within `$proximity` so we return true.

Comment: I think he meant proximity as in location in the array, not value.

Comment: You might be right, I'm very confused what he wants.  And I'm even more puzzled as to the potential application of this problem.

Comment: Ah no.. thought it works correct. Indeed its about location in array not values.

Comment: He wants to detect if all the keys of $imain appear "packed" inside vector $main. "packed" is meant order-free